# Should overflow respect max-height?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have two divs like this:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        b b b b b b b b bb
        b b b b b b b b b b b
        b b b b b b b b bb b 
        b b b b b b b b b b
    </div>
</div>

* { box-sizing: border-box; }
#a {
    width: 40px;
    max-height: 50vh;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
#b {
    width:100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

As you can see in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/yEWBM/6/) the inner div overflows the outer. This is because of the `max-height` on the outer div. If I replace it with `height` instead it works as expected.

But I want to use `max-height` since I want the height to be dynamic according to the content.

And I want the inner div to scroll and not overflow the outer div - when the outer div reaches `max-height`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

UPDATE: I think I have found a way to do it. Asking is always helpful. Moving the `50vh` to the inner div solves my problem in this case, see [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lborgman/yEWBM/7/).

But this is not a general solution.

Comment: Move `overflow-y: scroll;` to the outer div. Or better, use `overflow-y: auto;` instead.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling, but I just want the inner div to scroll.

Comment: So I assume that there are other elements inside the outer div?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea. I just removed them. For clarity, I thought... ;-)